# Quasi-projective variety with every points are in general position

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a quasi-projective variety. I will say every points of $X$ are in general position if any $n+1$ points of $X$ are linearly independent. I know every points of rational normal curve are in general position.

For Veronese map, generalization of rational normal curve, this is not always true. For example $[x^2:x:x:1:1:1]$ are in Veronese surface but $6$ points of them are not linearly independent.

Is there exist any other variety satisfying this condition? Or someone proved rational normal curve is the only quasi-projective variety satisfying this condition?

Comment: If $X$ is a non-degenerate smooth projective curve, the rational normal curve is the only possibility. Non-degenerate would imply that its degree is at least $n$. If the degree is bigger than $n$, a general hyperplane would intersect in more than $n$ points, which would be linearly dependent. So, it has to be precisely degree $n$ and then it is the rational normal curve.